# Fragment not replacing properly in second time android

Tags: android, fragment

I am having FragmentDetail.java file which consist of recylerview,when touch on recylerview the same fragment FragmentDetail.java is called,Same process when i repeat 4 5 times by touching two simultaneously recyler view items. It does not show the back fragment immediately.Instead it shows the fragment of recyler view items.First Fragmet contains recylerview on which click ProductMenu calls,and on Product menu recyler view click FragmentDetail.java calls.So know what my problem is that on back press fragments are not getting replace properly.Below is my code :-

FirstFragment

```
list_recycler.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), list_recycler, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Fragment fragment = new ProductMenu();

                fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();


                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_enter, R.anim.slide_exit);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
```

ProductMenu.java

```
Also contains the same code.In spite of fragment FragmentDetail fragment = new FragmentDetail();
```

FragmentDetail.java

```
FragmentDetail fragment = new FragmentDetail();
                ProductsBean productsBean = arr_related_product.get(position);              

                fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                //final int newBackStackLength = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() +1;
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_enter, R.anim.slide_exit);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by
:
Same process when i repeat 4 5 times by touching two simultaneously recyler view items. --> ?

At first instance i would suggest do

```
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_body, fragment);
```

instead of

```
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);

Let me know if it works ,also try to explain your problem little more with help of code
```

Comment: It means when i keep on clicking recyler view items,for example i click on "A" item then "B" then "A" again "B".Now when i click on back button,my fragment do not replace.

Comment: @ShivamKapoor ,my fragment do not replace-you can check that by putting a log in FragmentDetail.java's constructor.if everytime you click and log is displayed it means your fragmnts are created everytime you click.. which in turn means fragments are replaced. can you explain what is your exact requiremnt and and where u r stuck ?

Comment: Actually,I don't know where the problem has been occurring.But the output looks like fragments are not getting replace as if i have 3 Fragment from 3rd fragment it directly jumps on 1st fragment.And when jumps on first fragment the layout of 3rd fragment is visible not 1st fragment

Comment: did u try putting logs in constructor of every fragment.

Comment: Yes, it is getting correct data in adapter.But not getting why not replacing the fragment

Comment: can u post ur full code of on click in adapter  and fragment here ?also its not about data in adapter try to put a Log in fragment's constructor or oncreatview of fragment .. so that u can understand everytime a new fragmnet is created.

Comment: what do u mean not possible? U can always edit your question.      I think iif you are sure fragments are created everytime you just need to do this:fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).addtobackstack

Comment: something is horribly wrong.is your fragment product  is inside fragment detail i.e. frame layout of fragment detail is inside layout of fragment product if yes u need to use childfragmnet and if they are in same activity. u need a callback to activity to do a fragmnet transaction inside a fragmnet

Comment: When i press back button first time from fragment 3 to fragment 1,it works fine.When second time i repeat the process then last value which is added in first process pop out from stack.